# Why Can't I use my activated Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Properly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, reference

Hy All!

I try to develop some application for Windows Phone, but I have found some problems in my development environment. I've installed the Visual Studio 2012 Express for windows phone and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (with wp 8.0 SDK) 
in the same time, If I make a project in "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windws Phone" (I can make a simply Windows Phone app (I mean Visual C#/Windows Phone/Windows Phone App) )it works.. but if I try to upload on my phone it doesn't work well..

At the same time if I make a project in Visual Studio 2013 ( I can't make a same Windows Phone app(I mean "Visual C#/Store apps/Windows Phone Apps/Blank App(Windows Phone) ) In this project I can't use some namespaces e.g Windows.Forms. But I can upload the code on my phone( And If I tried the VS2012 projects I could upload them too)

I know for some reason the VS 2013 don't add the same references to the projects but I don't know why..

I tried to add the right references to VS13 projects but it doesn't work..

I think there is a solution but I don't know what.. Anybody?

Comment: If you could make it a but more clear!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2012 and you want to open a project that was created in Visual Studio 2013, you might be able to customize the project system to incorporate features of Visual Studio 2013. For information about how to do this,this will help you, see[How to: Modify a Project System So That Projects Load in Multiple Versions of Visual Studio.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh266706.aspx)